# Where is the default save location Flutter

Tags: csv, dart, save, flutter

when I write this code:

```
onSubmit(){
if(csvname.isEmpty){
  print('type name');
}else {
  File csvFile = new File(csvname + ".csv");

  print('yesssss');
}
}
```

Does it even create a csv file?

If yes where is it saved or how can I view it?

[Full Code / pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MTAvujEu)

Answer (score 1):

It is not saving it with the code you posted, see [this doc](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/). Here is an example on how to write to a local file:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async { 
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
return directory.path; 
} 
Future<File> get _localFile async { 
final path = await _localPath; return File('$path/counter.txt'); 
}

Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async { 
final file = await _localFile; // Write the file return file.writeAsString('$counter'); 
}
```